# A Pubular Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, calculation-puzzle

**Try to make sense of the puzzle below.**

---

*Circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4, circle5, circle6 and circle7 have radius r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6 and r7 respectively and periferi p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6 and p7 respectively. r7>r6>r5>r4>r3>r2>r1 and each circle share the same center. From p2 to p6 there are a number of straight lines connecting the two. The angle between two adjacent lines is always 18°.*

*If 0° is on an imaginary line going from the center to the top of circle7 and degrees are counted clockwise, then rank these ten (1-10) in correct order:*

**A** 127°, p6 • p7

**B** 18°, p4 • p5

**C** 33°, c • p1

**D** 257°, p5 • p6

**E** 44°, p3 • p4

**F** 79°, p1 • p2

**G** 353°, p5 • p6

**H** 3°, p3 • p4

**I** 100°, p4 • p5

**J** 187°, p2 • p3

Comment: Just wanted to say, the 'calculation'- tag is only  needed to calculate degrees. Once you realize what this is all about ('knowledge'-tag) it will make sense.

Comment: Are we supposed to understand what "The angle between two adjacent lines is always 18°" means, or is that also part of the puzzle?

Comment: ... Ah, hexomino's answer makes it pretty clear what it means, and indeed it was clearly deliberate that it wasn't made clearer in the question.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, I didn't want to be very clear what I meant by that.

Comment: Am I correct in surmising that "periferi" is "circumferences"? I've never hear of a "periferus"

Comment: @NoName I thought it was the same as the language I use, but it isn't. So should be "periphery".

Comment: You're probably thinking of "perimeter", which in the case of a circle would be the same thing as "circumference".

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Ok. I just thought perimeter/circumference *only* meant the actual length and not the name of the boundary itself, so wanted to specify that I meant the boundary only and not some length. In the language I speak we seperate those two. We call the boundary itself periphery and the length of it the circumference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ranking is as follows

> **H** (60 points)
>  **E** (54 points)
>  **C** (50 points)
>  **G** (40 points)
>  **F** (25 points)
>  **D** (16 points)
>  **I** (10 points)
>  **J** (3 points)
>  **B** (1 point)
>  **A** (0 points)

Reasoning

> The image description is that of a dartboard. The points I give in brackets represent the score for hitting that section of the dartboard. For example, hitting the dartboard at an angle of 3° between circles p3 and p4 represents a score of treble 20 (or 60). p7 represents the very outside of the dartboard so anything between p6 and p7 scores 0, while *c* represents the centre of the dartboard so anything between c and p1 scores 50 (a bullseye).

Title

> Darts is traditionally known as a pub game and many pubs have dartboards within.

Comment: You gt it! Great job!